# How do I provide navigation options on the sides of a centered logo?

Tags: html, css, navigation

I want to create a top header with the logo in the center and navigation options to it's left and right.

Below is what I have so far but not sure how to take it form there.  What can I do to accomplish this?

```
<div class="header">
    <div class="nav">
        <ul>
            <li>Option 1</li>
            <li>Option 2</li>
            <li>Option 3</li>
            <li>Option 4</li>
    <img class="logo_home" src="logo.png" height="100">
            <li>Option 5</li>
            <li>Option 6</li>
            <li>Option 7</li>
            <li>Option 8</li>
        </ul>
    </div>
</div>
```

CSS:

```
ul {
list-style:none;
}
li {
display:inline;
}
.header {
background-color: #999;
width: 100%;
height: 80px;
top: 0;
left: 0;
position:absolute;
}
 .logo_home {
display:block;
margin-left:auto;
margin-right:auto;
}
```

Comment: just to correct you about something which is not really relevant about what you are asking, but i see a mistake. `li` elements doesn't have `href` attribute.

Comment: @trajce sorry about that! I previously had an <a> tag in there but I removed it but I guess somehow I had the href part still there.

Comment: Check my answer, the menu is centered.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here is a [fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/NRd5H/2/) about what i think you are trying to achieve.
Change the `li inline to float` , and now the ul needs to be modified to your needs, so it can be centered.

here is another [fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/NRd5H/3/) which i think is exactly what you are trying to achieve.
you just need to remove  the `display:block` to the image and add `text-align:center` to the ul.
like this the elements are in the center.

So here is the html

```
<div class="header">
    <div class="nav">
        <ul>
            <li href="#">Option 1</li>
            <li href="#">Option 2</li>
            <li href="#">Option 3</li>
            <li href="#">Option 4</li>
            <li><img class="logo_home" src="logo.png" height="100" /></li>
            <li href="#">Option 5</li>
            <li href="#">Option 6</li>
            <li href="#">Option 7</li>
            <li href="#">Option 8</li>
        </ul>
    </div>
</div>
```

and here is your css

```
ul {
list-style:none;
    text-align:center;/* this will center your items*/
}
li {
    margin: 0 5px;
    display:inline;
}
.header {
background-color: #999;
width: 100%;
height: 80px;
}
 .logo_home {
margin-left:auto;
margin-right:auto;
/*removed display:block*/
}
```

Comment: Thanks @trajce! This will work but the menu options show under the header.  I need them to show alongside the logo.

Answer (score 1):

I changed `display: inline` from `li` to `float: left` and wrapped the `img` in the `li` tag. Looks like it is what you are looking for: [**FIDDLE**](http://jsfiddle.net/zTWB6/)

Comment: Thanks Artyom.  But it seems the logo doesn't center so not sure if that will work for me.

Answer (score 1):

I think this is what you want:

http://jsfiddle.net/VWcVw/

Setting everything to `display: inline` and putting the image in an `<li>` tag.

EDIT: Here's a better version, with the links on either side of the logo stacking horizontally. http://jsfiddle.net/VWcVw/1/

Comment: Thanks @uncleshelby.  The logo isn't centered and the menu options don't align horizontally..

Comment: I've update it, if I understand you correctly it should work better.

Answer (score 1):

That is to go further. I would divide left and right to two classes, also place links.

```
 .logo_home img{
margin:0 auto;
}
.navleft {
    float: left;
    width: 500px;
    height: 90px;
    margin: 0 auto;
    padding: 0;
    }
.navleft li {
    float: left;
    padding: 5px 5px 5px 5px;
}
.navright {
    float: right;
    width: 500px;
    height: 90px;
    margin: 0 auto;
    padding: 0;
    }
    .navright li {
    float: left;
    padding: 5px 5px 5px 5px;
}
</style>
</head>
<body>
<div class="header">
        <ul>
            <div class="navleft">
            <li><a href="#">Option 1</li>
            <li><a href="#">Option 2</li>
            <li><a href="#">Option 3</li>
            <li><a href="#">Option 4</li>
    </div>      
    <img class="logo_home" src="logo.png" height="100">
    <div class="navright">
            <li><a href="#">Option 5</li>
            <li><a href="#">Option 6</li>
            <li><a href="#">Option 7</li>
            <li><a href="#">Option 8</li>
        </ul>
    </div>
</div>
```

Answer (score 1):

Something like this would do it-

```
.left-li {
    float:left;
}
img {
    float:left;
}
.right-li {
    float:left;
}
```

Here's the HTML

```
<div class="header">
<div class="nav">
    <ul class="left-li">
        <li href="#">Option 1</li>
        <li href="#">Option 2</li>
        <li href="#">Option 3</li>
        <li href="#">Option 4</li>
    </ul>
<img class="logo_home" src="logo.png" height="100">
    <ul class="right-li">
        <li href="#">Option 5</li>
        <li href="#">Option 6</li>
        <li href="#">Option 7</li>
        <li href="#">Option 8</li>
    </ul>
</div>
```